# Truffle post-deployment actions

Tags: truffle, truffle-migration

I have 2 contracts that deployed with truffle. Now I extended it and my contracts require some bootstrap actions like "set some address" or "set in contract1 address of contract2".

I will not change contracts to make it dependable or mention one contract inside another. I want just to call function `contract1.setX(address_of_contract2)` and `contract2.setY(address_of_contract1)`.

How it could be done using truffle migration engine (not manually)?

Answer (score 9):

With help of [Karthikeyan Thangavel](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/users/10644/karthikeyan-thangavel) and Truffle docs I finally made it works:

```
module.exports = async function(deployer) {
  let aInst, bInst;

  await Promise.all([
    deployer.deploy(A),
    deployer.deploy(B)
  ]);

  instances = await Promise.all([
    A.deployed(),
    B.deployed()
  ])

  aInst = instances[0];
  bInst = instances[1];

  results = await Promise.all([
    aInst.setX(bInst.address),
    bInst.setY(aInst.address)
  ]);

  const xCheck = await aInst.x.call();
  const yCheck = await bInst.y.call();

  console.log('X: ', xCheck, bInst.address);
  console.log('Y: ', yCheck, aInst.address);
};
```

Comment: Not sure if web3 syntax has changed, but if you encounter the error `value.forEach is not a function` you need to put the parameters in the function call into an array, such as `aInst.setX([bInst.address])`

Answer (score 2):

I have a similar requirement (my contracts are named `NppToken` and `CrowdSale`), and here's how I'm handling it (note that `CrowdSale` uses the `NppToken`'s address as a constructor argument):

```
module.exports = async function(deployer) {
  deployer.deploy(NppToken).then(() => {
    return deployer.deploy(CrowdSale, NppToken.address);
  }).then(async () => {
    var token = await NppToken.deployed();
    await token.transferOwnership(CrowdSale.address);       
  });      
};
```

Comment: Did this work for you? I get a `syntax error: Unexpected token function`

Comment: Yes, this is my actual deployment script, but yours might be different depending on your design (e.g. if you don't have `transferOwnership` in your token).

Comment: ok. I have problem with async function() step. it says unexpected token 'function'

Comment: That's because it doesn't support the "async" keyword. Which Node version do you use? Anyway, you should be able to rewrite this as a chain of then-s, without async. The first async is not needed, you may start with removing it and see how the rest works.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve that using the promise function.

```
deployer.deploy(A).then(function() {
   deployer.deploy(B).then(funtion() {
       return A.setX(B.address);
     });
     return B.setX(A.address);
   });
}
```

Using the promise function you can do functionalities after deploying the contract.
For more details refer [truffle docs.](http://truffleframework.com/docs/getting_started/migrations#deployer-then-function-)

Comment: Thank you for help, I already reviewed documentatop you've pointed. Unfortunately it simply does not works. In your example I got error `TypeError: A.setX is not a function`.